# Coordinates of 3D vector in rotated coordinate system (without using a matrix)

Tags: matrices, vectors, coordinate-systems, rotations

**The problem:** 
There is a vector with coordinates X,Y,Z. This vector is in a coordinate sytem that has been rotated by A degrees along the X axis and B degrees along the Y axis. I would like to know the Z component of this vector in a non-rotated coordinate system.

**The question:** 
I can't seem to understand the usage of matrices and it seems that would be needed. Is their a series of operations after which I get the Z coordinate?

**A little backstory for those interested:**
I'm writing a drone flight controller and I can calculate the rotation of the drone using an accelerometer and a gyroscope. Now I would like to use the accelerometer to help with altitude controls. The XYZ values of that change depending on the rotation of the drone, but I need the change in altitude relative to the ground.

Comment: Welcome to Math.ME. I've attempted to answer. Besides the help you may get from here, you may consider to ask to move your question to [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The rotation matrices (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)) are:

\begin{align}
  Q_{\mathbf{x}}(A) &= \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 &  \cos A & \sin A \\
      0 & -\sin A & \cos A
    \end{bmatrix}, \\[8px]
  Q_{\mathbf{y}}(B) &= \begin{bmatrix}
       \cos B & 0 & -\sin B \\
       0 & 1 & 0 \\
       \sin B & 0 & \cos B
    \end{bmatrix}, \\[8px]
  Q_{\mathbf{z}}(C) &= \begin{bmatrix}
       \cos C & \sin C & 0 \\
      -\sin C & \cos C & 0 \\
       0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix},
\end{align}

The way to use them is to multiply one matrix by the current position $(x,y,z)$ vector to get the rotated vector $(x',y',z')$ and then multiply the other matrix by the resulting vector to get the result $(x'',y'',z'')$. However, from the information you provided I can't tell the exact order ad the angles may have their sign exchanged.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 x' \\
 y' \\
 z'
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 &  \cos A & \sin A \\
 0 & -\sin A & \cos A
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
 x \\
 y \\
 z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 x'' \\
 y'' \\
 z''
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos B & 0 & -\sin B \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \sin B & 0 & \cos B
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
 x' \\
 y' \\
 z'
\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

However, you may want to track your position and have the velocity vector in the drone coordinates and you may want to update your estimated position using numeric integration.

$$
x (t+\Delta t) = x(t) + v_x(t) \cdot \Delta t \\
y (t+\Delta t) = y(t) + v_y(t) \cdot \Delta t \\
z (t+\Delta t) = z(t) + v_z(t) \cdot \Delta t
$$

With the velocity vector $(v_x(t),v_y(t),v_z(t))$ being computed using the rotation matrices as before, starting with a vector like $(v_{fw},0,v_{up})$ or  $(v_{fw},v_{up},0)$, where $v_{fw}$ is the velocity forward in the coordinate system of the drone and $v_{up}$ is the velocity upward in that coordinate system.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the values differ depending on the order of the rotations. What should my order be if the rotations take place basically simultaniously or randomly?

Comment: The order of the rotations depends on the specifications of the drone. I'm sorry I can't be more helpful, but you might get there by trial and error. And note that the vertical axis might be $z$ or $y$ (or, in theory, $x$).

Comment: Probably it won't help much but the drone starts to rotate along the x axis and like a microsecond later it starts rotating along the y axis so they basically happen at the same time. I'm glad that u pointed me in the right direction, I will ask other communities as well

Comment: If the rotations are very small in the time resolution of the sensors, it probably will not make a big difference the order, although it will be more precise to have the correct order.